# Discord.js: Fetch displayName (nickname) based on user tag (username#1234)

Tags: discord.js

Is there a fetch or get function somewhere that would make this possible? I've been searching and searching with no success.

All help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

this code should do the job:

```
(server variable).members.cache.find(member => member.tag == 'tag#1234').displayName
```